# Converting docx to pdf ()

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, xsl-fo, docx4j

Few days ago I have faced with legacy code which processed .docx file as template and put values into placeholders. This system properly work until complex tables were inserted into template. I cant found solution except remake table. Maybe someone know trick or some setting in XSLFO.Conversion that helps to deal with this. here is simple code to reprodure behavior on my question

```
public class App {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
}

private static WordprocessingMLPackage wordComplex;

static {
    try {
        wordComplex = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(App.class.getResourceAsStream("complexTable.docx"));
        Conversion c = new Conversion(wordComplex);
        c.output((new FileOutputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/table.pdf")), new PdfSettings());
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Here is simple .docx example [complexTable.docx](http://p.mnd.io/dpPa9Q)

After conversion pdf document simply ignores first table and contains only second 
Here is result .pdf file [table.pdf](https://share.storycloud.com/#/view/bMVXtH)
Is anybody know workaround?

P.S. Sorry for my English. I hope my problem is clear from my post.
and I`m new on Stackoverflow, so cant post many links in normal way

Answer (score 0):

Its a bug.

Exploration of fix at https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/commit/be730349442923fa2d60e47630417a92405af719

A working alternative is to use Plutext's commercial PDF Converter.

Comment: Thank you, Jason. I'm glad for hearing from you. I hope my question helps you to make doc4j better.